# How to execute a script from a Perl telnet session?

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm fairly inexperienced with Perl, but I'm trying to create a Perl script which will run on a server that creates a telnet session to one of it's specific client machines and executes one of the scripts that resides on that client machine (so that it runs on the client, instead of trying to run it on the server).

I can't seem to find any examples of this kind of functionality, so I'm not even sure if it's possible.

This is what I initially thought would work:

```
my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new(Host=> $machineName, Timeout => 60) or die "Failed to create Telnet instance!";
$telnet->cmd("C:\\TestScript.cmd");
```

If I can't use telnet in Perl to accomplish this, is there something else that would do what I need that you could suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Edited to include the definition of $telnet

Comment: Looks to me like your existing code should work? What problems are you having? Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: It's just not executing the script at all.  It will execute from a normal command prompt telnet session, but it won't through how I'm doing it in perl.

Comment: But what evidence do you have that the script isn't being executed? Are you expecting to see output? Are you expecting to see some effect on the remote server? Saying "it's just not executing the script at all" isn't really answering my question.